# How to clear data from a JSON Array

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

I am working on a project where I have to clear all the data from a JSON array. There seems to be no method like **jsonArray.clear()**. Also tried  **jsonArray = new JSONArray()**. That too didn't worked. Suggestions please

Comment: why doesn't *jsonArray = new JSONArray()* work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just create a new JSONArray.

```
JSONArray otherJsonArray = new JSONArray();
```

Or iterate through the array and `remove(int index)` the indexes.

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#remove(int)

Comment: But there is no method remove(int) for JSONArray. My IDE is not showing that. I am using Android development tool(Eclipse)

Comment: No method `remove` on JSONArray? It's not static, so that's not surprising. It's an instance method, it would be `jsonArray.remove()`; unless you're not using the same org.json.JSONArray object?

Comment: Am using  org.json.JSONArray object. I changed that object to static and still it don't have the method remove()

Comment: You've misunderstood me, the method should exist on the **instance** (jsonArray), not on the JSONArray class as a static method.

Comment: if you iterate incrementally to remove(index) , first time will be 0 and will delete lets say from A,B,C  "A" after the second loop with 1 it will delete "C" and for the 3rd loop it will not delete nothing since there is no more things after C , so it will return B and will not delete all the array, you need to iterate decrementally to do it

Answer (score 4):

Just put `jsonArray = new JSONArray()`

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new one will work, unless you have passed it as a parameter to a method in which case you need to modify the referenced object as a new reference will not be seen by the calling method.

So if that is the case, do it backwards, that way you won't get your iterator exceeding bounds:

```
    int startingLength = someJsonArray.length();

    for (int i = startingLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        someJsonArray.remove(i);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

And you use that 
otherJsonArray is already  existing then you use

```
JSONArray otherJsonArray = new JSONArray("[]");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use someJsonArray.pop(index) to remove require record.
We can use this code in loop to remove all records.

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation where I want to remove all the entries from a JSONArray with key "Constants", which is an element in a JSONObject, creating a new JSONArray an assigning it does NOT clear the JSONArray, I have to iterate through the JSONArray and jsonArray.remove(i) on each of them, but there is a second method that works which involves removing the array element, in this case "Constants" completely from the JSONObject and re-adding it as a new JSONArray.

Hereis code with assignment of new array, which does not work, the JSONArray remained unchanged: (I tried both above suggestions for new JSONArray(); and new JSONArray("[]");

```
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(metadataOriginalJSON);
        if (jsonObj.isJSONArray("Constants")) {
            JSONArray constantsArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Constants");
            constantsArray = new JSONArray();
            metadataConstantsRemoved = jsonObj.toString();
        }
```

Here is code for the iteration through the JSONArray which worked:

```html
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(metadataOriginalJSON);
  if (jsonObj.isJSONArray("Constants")) {
      JSONArray constantsArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Constants");
      int i = 0;
      int arrayLenSanityCheckPreventEndlessLoop = constantsArray.length();
      while (constantsArray.length() > 0 && i < arrayLenSanityCheckPreventEndlessLoop) {
          constantsArray.remove(0);
          i++;
      }
      metadataConstantsRemoved = jsonObj.toString();
  }
```

The  2nd method that works by removing the entire JSONArray element and re-adding it to the JSONObject:

```html
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(metadataOriginalJSON);
  if (jsonObj.isJSONArray("Constants")) {
      jsonObj.remove("Constants");
      jsonObj.put("Constants", new JSONArray());
      metadataConstantsRemoved = jsonObj.toString();
  }
```